# Can we change the layout of the Built-in Calendar to show dates on one row instead of 5 rows?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have added the Calendar templates:

[image]

Which shows the calendar as follows:

[image: johnjohn123_1-1693740854167.png]

This shows the days divided into 5 rows. Can I modify this to show the days in one row instead?

Something like this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I think you will be able to do it. However, you will have to change all the formula at all the places like (x, y, height, width, etc.) which might take some time and mathematical calculations.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the reply, i tried to change the formulas, but first thing i faced is that i can only define max of 10 inside the WrapCount .. more than this number will not have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the formula from the Items propert of the default gallery.

The default gallery is a vertical gallery with the Wrap property set to 7. Replace it with a horizontal gallery and set template size to fit the day range to your screen.